# Workaround: Access variables of a liquid snippet rendered using the render tag

Tags: shopify, liquid, code-snippets

It's not possible to directly access variables from a rendered snippet (`{% render 'snippet' %}`). I've found this workaround, and it seems to work. Can somebody confirm this? Are there any drawbacks?

Snippet content:

```
{% assign test = 123 %}
{{ test }}
```

Section content:

```
{% capture test %}
  {% render 'snippet-test' %}
{% endcapture %}

{% assign test = test | plus: 0 %}
{{ test }}
```

I tested it an it worked...

Comment: Capture does just what you intended. You surround a block that results in a String with it, and you get the String in a variable. The call to render returns a String. So you are functioning within Liquid fine.

Comment: Yeah, this solution is totally fine, you could also use include 'snippet', it's deprecated as I know, but still works, this gives you the access to variables created in snippet